# AHK to reassign mouse indexes for RetroArch emulator

Tags: mouse, autohotkey, userscripts

I have an arcade build with lightguns that uses RetroArch. It relies on mouse indexes which can be obtained with a controller remap utility tool. This produces the following information

```
ControllerRemap Utility v0.0.11.0 - For Mame
(c) 2011 drventure Enterprises


Joystick Device List (Devices are in enumeration order) ...

   1.  'SindenLightgun', ID=1
   2.  'SindenLightgun', ID=2

Mouse Device List (Devices are in enumeration order) ...

   1.  'HID#VID_16C0_PID_0F38_MI_02_Col02#9_9dde10_0_0001#'
   2.  'HID#VID_16C0_PID_0F39_MI_02_Col02#9_230b0b6a_0_0001#'
   3.  'HID#VID_046D_PID_C534_MI_01_Col01#8_8d9ff6d_0_0000#'

End of list
```

This information is used to input any changes of the mouse index in the emulators config file (retroarch.cfg)

An AHK is executed and pulls this information but it always results in the wrong values

```
input_player1_mouse_index = "4"
input_player2_mouse_index = "3"
```

Should be

```
input_player1_mouse_index = "2"
input_player2_mouse_index = "1"
```

Finally here is the AHK in full (sorry if it is a little long) If someone happens to know what could be changed in the code to reflect the correct results that would be great.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance force


FileDelete, %A_Scriptdir%\list.txt
FileDelete, %A_Scriptdir%\retroarch.cfg.temp
ToolTip, Initializing Sinden Remap, mouseX, mouseY
iniread, P1pid, sindenremap.ini, general, P1pid, 1
iniread, P2pid, sindenremap.ini, general, P2pid, 2
iniread, P1name, sindenremap.ini, general, P1name, 0
iniread, P2name, sindenremap.ini, general, P2name, 0
iniread, guns, sindenremap.ini, general, guns, 0

tooltip

if (guns>0)
    gosub emuconfig

start:
MsgBox, 49, Sinden ID Remap utility configuration, This tool wil configure your lightgun indexes for Retroarch and Supermodel.`n`nUnplug your Sinden Lightgun(s) to and press OK to begin

Ifmsgbox, Cancel
    ExitApp
ifmsgbox, OK
    gosub checkgun1

checkgun1:
sleep 300
ToolTip, Reading device IDs, mouseX, mouseY
Run %comspec% /c `"%A_Scriptdir%\ControllerRemap.exe`" /list > list.txt ,, hide
sleep 500

ID = 0
numID = 0
guns = 0

ToolTip, Identifying Lightguns, mouseX, mouseY
Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\list.txt  , %A_scriptdir%\IDs.txt
{ 
ID := SubStr(A_LoopReadLine, 4 , 1)
if (ID > 0 AND ID < 20 )
{
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F01") or InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F02") or InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F38") or InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F39")
        guns += 1
    }
tooltip
If (guns>0)
{
    MsgBox, 17, Sinden ID Remap utility configuration, Gun(s) still connected. Disconnect your gun(s) and press OK
    gosub checkgun1
}

}
; detect player 1 gun----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
noguns:
FileDelete, %A_Scriptdir%\list.txt
MsgBox, 65, Sinden ID Remap utility configuration, Connect your Player 1 lightgun now.`n`nWait until it's detected by Windows (You will hear the USB connection sound) and press OK.
IfMsgBox, cancel
    ExitApp
sleep 1000
ToolTip, Reading device IDs, mouseX, mouseY
Run %comspec% /c `"%A_Scriptdir%\ControllerRemap.exe`" /list > list.txt ,, hide

sleep 500

ID = 0
numID = 0
guns = 0

ToolTip, Identifying Player 1 Lightgun, mouseX, mouseY
Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\list.txt  , %A_scriptdir%\IDs.txt
{ 
ID := SubStr(A_LoopReadLine, 4 , 1)
if (ID > 0 AND ID < 20 )
{
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F01")
    {
        P1pid = %ID%
        P1name = F01
        guns += 1
        break
    }
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F02")
    {
        P1pid = %ID%
        P1name = F02
        guns += 1
        break
    }
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F38")
    {
        P1pid = %ID%
        P1name = F38
        guns += 1
        break
    }
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F39")
    {
        P1pid = %ID%
        P1name = F39
        guns += 1
        break
    }
numID+=1    
}
}

if (guns=0)
    gosub noguns
ToolTip

; detect player 2 gun----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MsgBox, 36, Sinden ID Remap utility configuration, Lightgun1 (%P1name%) detected with index %P1pid%`nDo you have 2 lightguns?

IfMsgBox, Yes
{ 
    gosub detectp2gun
}
else
{
    P2pid=nul
    gosub saveini
}

detectp2gun:
FileDelete, %A_Scriptdir%\list.txt
MsgBox, 65, Sinden ID Remap utility configuration, Connect your Player 2 lightgun now.`n`nWait until it's detected by Windows (You will hear the USB connection sound) and press OK.
IfMsgBox, cancel
    ExitApp
sleep 1000
ToolTip, Reading device IDs, mouseX, mouseY
Run %comspec% /c `"%A_Scriptdir%\ControllerRemap.exe`" /list > list.txt ,, hide

sleep 500

ID = 0

ToolTip, Identifying Player 2 Lightgun, mouseX, mouseY
Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\list.txt  , %A_scriptdir%\IDs.txt
{ 
ID2 := SubStr(A_LoopReadLine, 4 , 1)
if (ID2 > 0 AND ID2 < 20 )
{
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F01")
    {
        if (ID2 != P1pid)
        {
            P2pid = %ID2%
            P2name = F01
            break
        }
    }
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F02")
    {
        
        if (ID2 != P1pid)
        {
            P2pid = %ID2%
            P2name = F02
            break
        }
    }
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F38")
    {
        if (ID2 != P1pid)
        {
            P2pid = %ID2%
            P2name = F38
            break
        }
    }
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "VID_16C0_PID_0F39")
    {
        if (ID2 != P1pid)
        {
            P2pid = %ID2%
            P2name = F39
            break
        }
    }
}
if (P2name!=0)
    break
}

if (P2name=0)
    gosub detectp2gun

guns+=1
ToolTip
gosub saveini

saveini:
change = 0
sleep 500
IniWrite, %p2pid%, sindenremap.ini, general, P2pid
iniwrite, %guns%, sindenremap.ini, general, guns
IniWrite, %P1pid%, sindenremap.ini, general, P1pid
Iniwrite, %P1name%, sindenremap.ini, general, P1name
Iniwrite, %P2name%, sindenremap.ini, general, P2name

emuconfig:

Tooltip, Number of guns: %guns%`nPlayer 1 %P1name%: %P1pid% `nPlayer 2 %P1name%: %P2pid%
sleep 1000


;check if PID have changed--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ToolTip, Checking if indexes have changed, mouseX, mouseY
Run %comspec% /c `"%A_Scriptdir%\ControllerRemap.exe`" /list > list.txt ,, hide
sleep 500
currentguns = 0
newP1pid = %P1pid%
newP2pid = %P2pid%
numID = 0
Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\list.txt  , %A_scriptdir%\IDs.txt
{ 
IDC := SubStr(A_LoopReadLine, 4 , 1)
if (IDC > 0 AND IDC < 20 )
{
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, P1name)
    {
        if (IDC != P1pid)
        {
            tooltip, Lightgun 1 Index changed. Adjusting new index
            newP1pid = %IDC%
            
            change = 1
        }
        currentguns += 1
    }
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, P2name)
    {
        if (IDC != P2pid)
        {
            tooltip, Lightgun 1 Index changed. Adjusting new index
            newP2pid = %IDC%
            change = 1
            
        }
        currentguns += 1
    }
    numID +=1
}
}

if (guns!=currentguns)
{
    MsgBox, 53, Sinden ID Remap utility configuration, One or both lightguns can't be found.`n(Re)Connect your guns and click Retry or press Cancel to run the configuration tool.
    ifmsgbox, Retry
        gosub emuconfig
    ifmsgbox, Cancel
        gosub start
}

if (change=1)
{
    P1pid = %newP1pid%
    P2pid = %newP2pid%
    gosub saveini
}
tooltip

ToolTip, Finding emulator, mouseX, mouseY
; Retroarch config----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if FileExist(A_scriptDir "\retroarch.exe")
{
    P1pid := numID - P1pid
    if (guns > 1)
        P2pid := numID - P2pid
    else
        P2pid = nul
ToolTip, Editing Retroarch.cfg, mouseX, mouseY
Loop, read, retroarch.cfg  , retroarch.cfg.temp
{
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "input_player1_mouse_index")
    {
        Fileappend, input_player1_mouse_index = `"%P1pid%`"`n, retroarch.cfg.temp
    }
    else if InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "input_player2_mouse_index")
    {
        Fileappend, input_player2_mouse_index = `"%P2pid%`"`n, retroarch.cfg.temp
    }
    else
    {
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, retroarch.cfg.temp
    }
}
sleep 500
FileMove, retroarch.cfg, retroarch.cfg.bak, 1
sleep 500
Filemove, retroarch.cfg.temp, retroarch.cfg, 1
sleep 2000
}

; Supermodel config----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ToolTip, Editing Supermodel.ini, mouseX, mouseY
if FileExist(A_scriptDir "\supermodel.exe")
{
    ;Write changes to supermodel.ini
    ;Player1 GUN
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P1pid%_XAXIS`,JOY1_XAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputGunX  
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P1pid%_YAXIS`,JOY1_YAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputGunY 
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_A`,JOY1_BUTTON1`,MOUSE%P1pid%_LEFT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputTrigger
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_S`,JOY1_BUTTON2`,MOUSE%P1pid%_RIGHT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputOffscreen
    
    ;Player1 ANALOG GUN
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P1pid%_XAXIS`,JOY1_XAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogGunX  
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P1pid%_YAXIS`,JOY1_YAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogGunY 
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_A`,JOY1_BUTTON1`,MOUSE%P1pid%_LEFT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogTriggerLeft
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_S`,JOY1_BUTTON2`,MOUSE%P1pid%_RIGHT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogTriggerRight
    
    ;Player1 ANALOG JOYSTICK
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P1pid%_XAXIS`,JOY1_XAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogJoyX  
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P1pid%_YAXIS`,JOY1_YAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogJoyY 

    
    if (guns>1)
    {
    ;Player2 GUN
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P2pid%_XAXIS`,JOY2_XAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputGunX2
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P2pid%_YAXIS`,JOY2_YAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputGunY2
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_Z`,JOY2_BUTTON1`,MOUSE%P2pid%_LEFT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputTrigger2
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_X`,JOY2_BUTTON2`,MOUSE%P2pid%_RIGHT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputOffscreen2

    ;Player2 ANALOG GUN
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P2pid%_XAXIS`,JOY2_XAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogGunX2
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"MOUSE%P2pid%_YAXIS`,JOY2_YAXIS`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogGunY2
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_Z`,JOY2_BUTTON1`,MOUSE%P2pid%_LEFT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogTriggerLeft2
    iniwrite, %a_Space%`"KEY_X`,JOY2_BUTTON2`,MOUSE%P2pid%_RIGHT_BUTTON`" , %A_ScriptDir%\Config\Supermodel.ini, global, InputAnalogTriggerRight2

    }
}

ToolTip, Closing, mouseX, mouseY
Sleep 2000
ToolTip
ExitApp


ToolTip
ExitApp
```

Comment: The code looks easy enough to understand but I didn't run it... Can you expand on why the "should be" values should be that? I.e., why should they be that? What are the "should be" values supposed to correlate to? Or perhaps the flip side of that coin... why are the actual results wrong, implicitly or explicitly? What makes them wrong, or how can you tell they are wrong? Separately, what are the associated name values saved to the INI file, vs. expected?  And do the associated name values match what you would expect, or not expect?

Comment: Thanks for responding, the AHK executes a 'controller remap utility' app. This results in listing all joystick and mouse devices connected via USB to the PC. It is required to run in the root dir of RetroArch so it can modify (if needed) retroarch.cfg. The initial results are correct in the Mouse Device List numerated 1 and 2 (top of post) But the script is numbering them 3 and 4 however for the edits. It is counting down from the 2 top lines of the Joystick Device List. So I think if there is a way to have the script ignore Joystick Device List then the edited entries would be correct.

Comment: So in the script if there is way to only use the numerated results from the Mouse Device List only and ignore Joystick Device List than the correct value would be changed if needed for input mouse index

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to get a debugger that will allow you to run the script in debug mode (step by step), to step through and examine what's actually happening. While the assumption in the comments is reasonable (i.e., ignoring the joystick devices), that may not actually be what's happening. There is also code I can see on inspection, that would flip the numbers, which may be what's supposed to remove the joystick items, so that may not be executing properly, or something else may be happening.

For example, the block of code under FileExist(A_scriptDir "\retroarch.exe"), flips the detected value of P1pid and P2pid, which is what gets written to disk later on. If there were 5 total items detected (including joystick items), I would expect that code to execute and then player 1 mouse index would be 5-4=1 and player 2 mouse index would be 5-3=2, where 4 and 3 are the values you're showing above, and 5 would be the total number of joystick+mouse items detected. Just a hypothetical.

I would recommend downloading SciTE4AutoHotkey, then step through the code step by step and see what's happening.